# How can I dynamically load perl extensions in an embeded perl interpreter?

Tags: perl, dynamic, interpreter, embedded-language

I am embeding perl interpreter in my C code (what fun!).

I need to dynamically load perl extensions (an extension that extends perl, written in C). When I run a perl script (using my embeded perl interpreter) that needs to use that extension, it will work!

Comment: This question is not relevant to embedded programming, unless you are changing the perl interpreter to run on an embedded processor.  See stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded

Comment: I agree with Ian on the "embedded" tag. Thus, I removed it and instead added "perl-xs", which more clearly marks it as related to extending perl with C.

Comment: I disagree with this comment. embedding is not related only to embedded programming, but also in many programming areas as to "take an object from one environment and put/use in another". see following links: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html#Embedding-Perl-under-Win32, http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ext/embedding.html, http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/264, and so on. the tag 'perl-xs' (extending) is related to this question but it is not the main issue that was asked. the main issue is: "when embedding the interpreter, how to do dynamic loading ?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to have pass an `xs_init` function to `perl_parse` that will provide `DynaLoader::boot_DynaLoader` for you. You can write those automatically with `ExtUtils::Embed`.

With that, all you need to do is, for example, eval some code that will load an extension written in C.

["Using Perl modules, which themselves use C libraries, from your C program" in perlembed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html#Using-Perl-modules,-which-themselves-use-C-libraries,-from-your-C-program) explains this in detail.